# Loop and variable names

Tags: r, loops

Here is a litte example:

```
temp<-0
a1<-1
a2<-2
a3<-3
a4<-4

for(i in 1:4) {
  temp<-temp+a*     # temp+a1|a2|a3|a4 ...
}
```

How can I realise that?

New example:

```
matrix1<-cbind(rep(Sys.time(),4),matrix(1:8,nrow=4))
matrix2<-cbind(rep(Sys.time(),4),matrix(2:9,nrow=4))
matrix3<-cbind(rep(Sys.time(),4),matrix(3:10,nrow=4))

temp<-matrix(0,nrow=4,ncol=2)

for(i in 1:3) {
  temp<-temp+ ?  # temp = matrix1[,2:3] + matrix2[,2:3] + matrix3[,2:3]
}
```

It´s only an example. I have 50-150 matrices

Comment: Please specify what you are trying to achieve, it's totally unclear so far.

Comment: Why not use `a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4); temp <- sum(a)`?  In other words, make use of the fact you can perform vectorised operations in R.

Comment: I added a new example.

Comment: You should not have 50-150 matrices in 50-150 different objects in your environment. You should learn to use lists. Then it is as simple as looping over the list index, or use functions like `lapply` and `Reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe put these values in one vector:

```
temp<-0
a<-c(1,2,3,4) #or 1:4

for(i in 1:4) {
  temp<-temp+a[i]     # temp+a1|a2|a3|a4 ...
}
```

If this is what you really need to do I recommend using sum function like this:
`sum(a)`

But if you want to paste more complex commands try this:

```
> a1 <- 1; a2<-2
> temp <- 0
> for(i in 1:2) temp <- eval(parse(text="temp+a"%+%i))
> temp
[1] 3
```

`%+%` is operator for string concatenation from `stringi` package.
To install this please run:

```
install.packages("stringi")
require(stringi)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concat the name and index with `paste0`, than just use `get` to refer to variable via string name.

```
for(i in 1:4) {
    temp <- temp + get(paste0("a", i))
}
```